# Firebase Functions: Only getting undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

So, my issue is, that I cannot seem to get anything to `console.log` in my firebase functions.

In `functions/index.js` I have:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

try { 
  admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
} catch (e) {
  console.log("dbMessagesUpdate initializeApp failure");
}

exports.onMessagesUpdate = functions.database.ref("/messages/basic_message").onCreate((snap, context) => {
console.log("SNAP: ", snap.val());
});
```

In Terminal:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
// The function shows up in my functions list. 
// also, it would be nice to just test functions locally, but when I run 
// `firebase serve --only functions` I get An unexpected error occurred...
```

Then, I add new data to `/messages/basic_message` on my Firebase Realtime Database.

When I check the logs in my firebase functions website dashboard, it shows an (i) information tag but nothing else.

In terminal:

```
firebase functions:log
```

returns:

```
2018-05-27T19:14:54.159Z N onMessagesUpdate: undefined
```

Not sure what I am missing. Is this issue due to not setting up billing info on Firebase? Why `undefined`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`functions.database.ref("/messages/basic_message").onCreate()` only responds for a newly created node called `/messages/basic_message`.  If that node existed prior to a change, it wouldn't invoke the function.

If you you want to know if that node changed in any way after creation, use `onUpdate()` instead.

If you want to know if a child as created anywhere under `/messages/basic_message`, use this instead:

```
functions.database.ref("/messages/basic_message/{id}").onCreate(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

`/messages/basic_messages` probably already exists.

Instead check for elements that are added to it:

```
var ref = functions.database.ref("/messages/basic_messages");

ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
  var newMessage = snapshot.val();
  console.log("Author: " + newMessage.author);
  console.log("Previous Post ID: " + prevChildKey);
});
```

Comment: Hey, this answer led me to the changes that fixed it: You were right about the wrong reference, but `onChildAdded()` doesn't seem to work with `functions.database.ref()`. I had to stay with `onCreate()` but my ref had to change to `ref("/messages/basic_messages/{messageId}")` If you could change your suggestion details (I agree with the suggestion intent) I will mark yours as the correct answer